# How to improve $listen array for EventServiceProvider in Laravel master

Tags: events, laravel-5

does anyone think about how to improve **$listen** array in **EventServiceProvider** for **Laravel5**. I have a more than **100** **Events**, and it hurts me to add new events and handlers.

Thanks for your help!
Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a queue provider or just the event listening? If you set up the events with a queue system and then turn on the queue listener you wouldnt need to define them all. The queue will handle it. I've done it with SQS.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your comment. I describe all event in EventServiceProvider in $listen array, and subscribe for this events. and that's all...

Comment: I've checked it, I use queues with redis for background Jobs like sending email, checking smth, etc. But what I asked is for Events, not for Jobs. I don't think that using Jobs instead of Events will be good idea.

Comment: Hey I just realized that you could always switch into groups of event service providers. Then rather than having one service provider for events you could register a few for different purposes. I hope things worked out.